# Primefaces fileupload multiple file error

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

The Fileupload works!
But if i added two files i the data in the files a not corrected stored.
If i look in the debugging mode it works. I think the problem is the time between one file and the over file. Can i add sleep or somehting else that only the first file will add and than the second. Like sequential and not parallel?

The fileupload code looks like:

```
<p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" label="#{msgs.durchsuchen}" uploadLabel="#{msgs.upload}" cancelLabel="#{msgs.cancel}" fileUploadListener="#{importData.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"  
            update="Collection,messages" sizeLimit="1000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt|csv)$/" onstart="submitCollection()"/>
```

To get the data in the right order for the csv format i added this code:

```
List<String> attr = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String[]> value = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            InputStream temp = event.getFile().getInputstream();
            Boolean firstLine = true;
            if(temp != null){
                /*"\\s*;\\s*" die rechte Seite und die Linke Seite wird durch den ; getrennt.*/         
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(temp, "UTF-8");    
                while(scanner.hasNextLine()){ //Es wird immer eine komplette Zeile überprüft

                    String line = scanner.nextLine(); //Die komplette Zeile wird in einen String gespeichert
                    String[] fields = line.split(";"); //Anschließend wird die Zeile an dem ; zerschnitten.

                    if(firstLine){
                        for(String field : fields){
                            attr.add(field);
                            System.out.println(field);
                        }     
                        firstLine = false;
                    }else{                      
                        value.add(fields);                                              
                    }                               
                }
                tempListMap = readImportFile.getTheDocInformation(attr, value); //In der Klasse werden die Keys und Values in einer Map zusammengebaut.
                scanner.close();
```

Any idea?

Comment: It looks like you didn't enable multiple fileupload. Maybe this helps.

Comment: thank you. i must missed it.

Comment: I missed multiple, but the drag and drop with multiple files don't work. Can't i upload multiple files with drag and drop?